Fetching results in a long “pending” time in Chrome before transfer starts
I have an issue where my app occasionally takes a very long time to load. Investigating this in Chrome devtools/in the network tab (see below), I can see that some of the resources that I am requesting are stuck in a "pending" state, sometimes for as long as a 1 minute before the transfer actually starts.

I also saw for the first time today a QUIC protocol error which occurred after one resource was pending for more than 5 minutes (could be a red herring, but I am unsure).
While I would love a solution to this problem, any hints on what I should be looking for or how I can debug this in the comments would also really be appreciated. The URL to this site is public and is: https://rosonweb.io
One thing I have observed so far is that refreshing several times seems to induce the problem while opening the same site in incognito causes the web app to load instantly without any issues...
